# Refreshing the database using C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a Windows form application with few text boxes, button and a data grid view that is connected to a SQL Server database.

When the button is clicked data is entered to the database, but it does not show in the grid view. I tried refreshing the grid view, still no result.

To see the entered data I have to manually refresh the database. Then the entered data is shown in the grid view, when I run the application.

Please tell me a way to update database in the button click event. Or another way to show the data in gridview as soon as they have been entered to the database.

Comment: Please share what you have implemented so far!

Comment: Are you sure you're writing to the same copy of the database? Does your connection string use 'AttachDbFileName'? Are you using try/catch or otherwise ignoring exceptions?

Comment: well, nothing much except for the connecting and inserting data to the database. i connected the grid view using the grid view tasks, no coding in the database.

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand_ yes, im sure. but there is no 'AttachDbFileName' in the connection string. i used Try/catch to entering of data. but i did not do any codings for the data grid view.

Comment: So check the data in the database instead of using the data grid.

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually refresh the database'?

Comment: @ OzrenTkalcecKrznaric_i have to close the running application and refresh database in VS server explorer.